# asp.net MVC 5 DependencyResolver

Tags: unity-container, ioc-container, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using Unity Dependency Injection in my project and when
upgrading to new ASP.NET MVC5 make a problem of "Entry point was not found" what happened to *DependencyResolver*  and how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide more details?  I'm using Unity 3 along with [Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/).  My code `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));` works OK.

Comment: can you upgrade it to mvc5 and razor3 without problem ?

Comment: Yes, I upgraded following  [How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2). Perhaps there is an issue with the specific bootstrapper used to integrate Unity with MVC (e.g. Unity.Mvc4 if you are using that...you didn't mention)?

Comment: Its not just Unity.  I'm running into the same issue with Autofac.

Comment: Switching from my custom unity dependency resolver class to the one that comes out of the unity box solved my issue. Big thanks @Tuzo for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Like Tuzo said, try upgrading our Unit MVC bootstrapper to the version that supports MVC5.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc5/

Comment: We're actually using Autofac instead of Unity but I'm getting the exact error as mentioned above. Updating the DI package solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of System.Web.WebPages.Razor, update it to latest version.

Try Unity with Unity.Mvc5 1.1.0 nuget package. You can find a step-by-step guide below.
[MVC 5 with Unity for Dependency Injection](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2015/04/mvc-5-with-unity-for-dependency.html)

Comment: Package appears to be broken and has not been updated in a while